# What is the ccallable macro for in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have recently seen that there is a macro defined in `base/c.jl` called `ccallable`, but it is not clear to me what its usefulness is. It seems to be undocumented.

Comment: It makes possible to call a Julia function directly from C. See https://docs.juliahub.com/PackageCompiler/MMV8C/1.2.1/devdocs/binaries_part_2.html  Since I have not used it myself perhaps others will elaborate more on that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation a little more carefully, I would summarise the usefulness of this macro as follows:

> Make the annotated function be callable from C using its name. This can, for example, be used to expose functionality as a C-API when creating a custom Julia sysimage.